# undefined method `movie_reviews' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I made a simple test app for reviewing movies. I get this error throughout my application.
I've set inheritance in models (using API for movie data) and other standard things, but I don't know why I'm getting this error.
For example, visiting this URL -

```
...movies/%23<Tmdb::Movie:0x00000002d30728>/movie_reviews/new
```

I get the error

```
app/controllers/movie_reviews_controller.rb:17:in `new'

def new
 @movie_review = @movie.movie_reviews.new
end
```

Here's source code on GH: https://github.com/Xantax/sample_movies

Comment: Is @movie nil? Also, are you sure you're using new correctly here?

Answer (score 1):

You never set the instance variable `@movie` in the new action of your controller. Every instance variable returns nil if it hadn't been set before. so `@movie` is nil and it is expected that you'll get this error.

Another thing you should pay attention to is the URL.
The URL path should have a numeric movie ID instead of `%23<Tmdb::Movie:0x00000002d30728>`. This may prevent you from finding the movie you'd like in the controller easily.
If it had been 23 for example you could just simply:

```
@movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
```

because /movies/23/more_reviews/new puts 23 into `params[:id]`

Hope this helps you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, **you're trying to call a method on a `nil` (undeclared) object**

In your case, the undeclared object is `@movie`, and will mean you have to declare it somehow. The solution to this is to create the object (typically using an `ActiveRecord` method). As mentioned by Erez, you could use:

```
@movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
```